# while i am login it shows me the error Server Application Unavailable

Tags: asp.net

While i am trying to login to my asp.net application it show an error kindly help me out to solve this issue

**ERROR:**

Server Application Unavailable

The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.

Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.

Comment: Have you checked the event log for more information?

Comment: yes i check the login process although i am deployed to the localhost it's working fine on the localhost but not on the live server